# C++: looking for thread based a parallel kd tree library

Tags: c++, kdtree, parallel-processing

Are there some implementation for KD-Tree on shared memory machines?

thanks
Arman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[libkdtree++](http://libkdtree.alioth.debian.org/) or [kdtree](http://code.google.com/p/kdtree/)

Comment: Thanks, but both of them are serial libraries. I cannot build the tree in parallel from different threads.

Comment: I was looking for such a library myself, but with no luck. You will probably have to implement it yourself, or extend/change an existing opensource solution. I did the second thing with ANN, but i did not parallelize tree creation, just searching.

Comment: @PeterK: Thanks peter for response. I have a oct-tree with fully MPI parallel implementation, so I was thinking to save the time and use some opensource with thread based parallel version. So if I will succeed with my implementation, I am  going to put it in the google.code to share with others.

Comment: @Arman: You are wellcome. I believe my extension to the ANN library will be publicly (opensource) available soon (in a few weeks i hope). It allows parallel searching though not addition or removal of records. I even think that is not possible since the tree structure changes if some record is added or removed, thus it breaks any search being done.

Comment: You might have some luck if you start with kdtree, the libkdtree++ is so messed that it's painful to watch. Like they spent 99% of the time playing with templates and trying to use every STL template in the book and for some reason every single name starts with _ or __ - function names, params ... Maybe that's a new way to hide an algorithm :-))